# (x86 Assembly) Jumping back to location before you jumped?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I'm trying to jump back to the location I jumped from in an 16-bit x86 instruction set program. I'm currently doing a long jump to a location outside of the sector (1 sector over) but I want to jump back after the my code outside of the sector has run.

```
;Loading new file into segmented memory 0001:2345
mov bx, 0x0001   ;Setting the location to load the module into memory
mov es, bx
mov ds, bx
mov bx, 0x2345

mov ah, 02   ;Set to read disk
mov al, 1    ;Reading 1st sector from disk
mov ch, 0    ;First cylinder
mov cl, 2    ;Reading the physical second sector
mov dh, 0    ;Reading first head
mov dl, 0    ;Reading from the first drive
int 13h      ;Execute interrupt to load disk sector into memory

jmp word 0x0001:0x2345 ;Jump to the location in memory that the we just loaded into memory.
;Where I'd like to jump back to so I can continue to execute some code.
```

This code successfully jumps me to the new memory location and executes the code I loaded there. I can't quite figure out how to get back to my main program. I'm thinking there must be a way to store my address location before I make the jump and use it to make the return, but I haven't been able to properly get jmp to play nice with addresses that I've stored in the stack.

Does anyone with some wisdom in x86 have any suggestions?

Comment: *I'm thinking there must be a way to store my address location before I make the jump and use it to make the return* yeah it's called `call`; that's how you call functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to do what you ask is to use a `call` instruction, which pushes the current instruction pointer (and code segment in case of a "far" call, i.e. a call that changes the code segment) and jumps to the specified address. To get back to the next instruction, the callee will have to do a `ret` (in particular, a `retf` to return from a far call). Hence, you'll probably do something like

```
call word 0x0001:0x2345
```

and at the end of the callee

```
retf
```